# TortoiseGit: Is it possible to clone only particular folder in a git repo?

Tags: git, clone, tortoisegit

I commit my project into a git repo via Visual Studio. My team has to download only the exes and deploy.
Is it possible via TortoiseGit to download specific files instead of a repo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+single+folder

Comment: Use TortioseSVN to download a particular folder GitHub.  I know it's counter-intuitive, using an SVN client on a server that mainly deals with Git, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In General that is not possible. The concept of Git and, therefore, TortoiseGit is that you have to fully clone a repository.

Exception is if there is a web interface such as GitHub/GitLab which allow individual file access.

PS: Executables should not be part of the repository. You already have the source code and can easily build each state.

PSS: Maybe a hook or CI/CD approach helps to upload your binary somewhere automatically.